# How to first check the array in mongodb and then add item if it does not already contain this item(string)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here is my code till now:

```
Scorecard.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: fielderRoleInfo.player_id },
    { $push: { ["score." + n + ".catches"]: dismissedPlayer } },
    function (err, docs) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        // console.log("Updated Fielder : ", docs);

      }
    }
  );
```

dismissedPlayer and fielderRoleInfo are defined somewhere else in code. This code add duplicate strings(dismissedPlayer) in catches array inside the object in score array( score is an array of objects). I want to first check if string(dismissedPlayer) exist in array and if it not exist, then only add in array. Note: dismissedPlayer is a variable and it will have dynamic values

Comment: instead of `$push` , use `$addToSet`

Comment: In the update's filter you can include condition if the dismissedPlayer exists in the array field (you can use the `$eq` operator).

Comment: See this example in the MongoDB Manual: [Query an Array Element](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element). You can use the `$eq` or `$ne` operators, as needed.

Comment: so if it possible I make answer and accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

Replacin $push with $addToSet work for me.

> The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is
> already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.